# Disable Debug Log Programmatically

Tags: debug, wp-debug, errors

I'm trying to disable `WP_DEBUG_LOG` if and only if `debug.log` exists. I'd like to hook into `wp_footer` and test if the file exists and if so disable my debug log. All I've found though is that `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is a constant and can only be changed from the `wp-config.php` file which is too early for my case. Is there a way to change it from a constant on install and keep it working as normal?

My only other thought is to create an option on install in the options table and just check it every time `wp-config` loaded to see if the value has changed but I was wanting to avoid that.

Granted I could check if the file exists before I define `WP_DEBUG_LOG` but somebody would have to view a page twice before debug log actually exists and is detected by the `file_exists()` (since it's run very early) which is not optimal.

Does anybody know of a workaround to programmatically turn off `WP_DEBUG_LOG`?

Comment: You can check or load `WP_DEBUG_LOG` in a mu-plugin. Debug log just loads `ini_set('error_log')` so you can set it that way as well instead of using a WP constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wyck was right, ( well sorta :P ) you can set error logs but

1) You need to enable debugging

2) `ini_set('log_errors', 1);` or 0 for `false`

3) You need to set a log location via `ini_set('error_log, $location)`

Once you have that set you can then if need be test if said file exists via `$location` and turn off `log_errors` by setting its value to 0.